# How to install robot_upstart?

Tags: ros, rosinstall, robot-upstart, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is a total newbie question but I have absolutely no idea how to install a package from the wiki.

http://wiki.ros.org/robot_upstart

I've tried downloading it from git and running install.py but when I run `$rosrun robot_upstart <anything>` I get the error package 'robot_upstart' not found.
I don't really understand how to use rosinstall or if this is even the right place to use it.

What should I be doing to install a package? Please assume I know nothing :)

Thank you!!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/221386/how-to-install-robot_upstart?/) by [twigs](https://answers.ros.org/users/25102/twigs/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2015-11-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As you can see on the wiki page you linked, `robot_upstart` has been released into Hydro, Indigo and Jade (the `released` badge right under the *Package Summary*). Assuming you are using an Ubuntu flavour / variant, this means that you can install it using:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-$distro-robot-upstart
```

in a terminal (or look for the `ros-$distro-robot-upstart` package in `synaptic` or whatever package manager you are using). `$distro` will be one of `hydro`, `indigo` or `jade`, depending on what you have installed on your machine / robot.

No need to build from source or `git clone`. In fact, I'd avoid installing anything from source, unless you need to edit packages, it hasn't been released yet or a release with a (critical) bug fix hasn't been released.

Pre-built binaries will be much faster to install, dependency resolution will have already been done for you and you'll get automatic updates.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-11-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [twigs](https://answers.ros.org/users/25102/twigs/) on 2015-11-23**:
Hmmmm, this doesn't seem to find anything... I'll keep trying

`sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-robot-upstart` or `ros-indigo-robot_upstart` or `ros-indigo-devel-robot-upstart` or `ros-indigo-devel-robot_upstart`

all return unable to locate

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-11-23**:
If you are on Indigo, `sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-robot-upstart` should definitely work.